# Area units for output polygon in WGS 84 UTM Zone 32N using QGIS

Tags: coordinate-system, qgis-2, wgs84, utm, units

I am calculating the area of my polygon and I have used WGS 84 UTM zone 32N to calculate the area (using geometry on the field calculator) of my polygon, and I obtained 745461 (without units).

How do I determine whether it is in square metres or square kilometres?

Comment: It will be in the units of your projection, in this case metres.

Comment: 745461 sq km would be an area larger than Chile or Zambia (though smaller than Turkey or Pakistan), while 745461 sq m would be one third the area of Monaco.  But what's six orders of magnitude between friends?

Answer (score 2):

I think we can over complicate this answer. It is meters, as UTM Zones are **almost always** going to use meters as their unit (exceptions are so rare as to not be worth a mention). If you suspect you are using something that is not meters it will say so.

Use this site as it is software independent if you must look it up.

http://spatialreference.org/

Then search for your system

http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/wgs-84-utm-zone-32n/html/

You will get this. Read down and look for the unit (the lower one).

> PROJCS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 32N",

```
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
    UNIT["degree",0.01745329251994328,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
UNIT["metre",1,
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
PARAMETER["central_meridian",9],
PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
AUTHORITY["EPSG","32632"],
AXIS["Easting",EAST],
AXIS["Northing",NORTH]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should check a few items:

- check layer CRS
- check project CRS (set automatically reprojection on the fly in: Settings > Options > CRS)
- After open vector layer in QGIS use tool "identify Feautures" and select one feauture
- In "Identify Results" dock window "expand all" and look for area units

Now you can use "Filed calcuator" or Vector > Geometry Tools > Export/Add Geometry columns - to compare results from "identify Feautures" and Field calculator.

Comment: Great propositions to all, it was really helpful. I think! I think Zoltan had a pretty practical way of verifying which is always valid for all CRS projections.

Comment: @Zoltan and all the others, though it indicates m, the values are just too small to be real. 0.00169 for a road segment that shows 154m on Google Earth

Comment: I am using WGS 84 / UTM 32N for 11.3 and 11.5 (W and E respectively)

Comment: Can you share sample data ?

Comment: I can't upload data, and the JSON file is too long and exceeds the word limit

Comment: Wait I have been missing it all through, I figured out the problem. I changed the CRS of the project but not of the layer. Thanks

Comment: Thats good that problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

The unit of the projection is used for area calculation, meter or decimal degree or feet. Check Settings/Options/Crs, see screenshot:

[image]